# JQuery loader while AJAX is working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am having an issue with AJAX being the dominant action in a JQuery function.  I would like this code to be somewhat linear and async doesn't seem to have an effect.  What I am trying to do is display a "loader", and then hide said "loader" when the script has finished.  I have many other instances of this but without the AJAX call.  Instead I have used $.post, but for this specific instance $.ajax meets my needs better.

Desired result:

I would like to display the "loader" the instant "select_add_user".change is called.  I would like the loader to stay put until the script (including the ajax) is finished.

Actual result:

The ajax loads FIRST without even displaying the loader,  and then on "#select_sub_group".append the loader displays for a millisecond while the script appends my HTML.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#select_user_add").change(function(){
$("#loader:hidden").show("fast"); 
$('#select_sub_group').html('');
var appendD = "";
txt=$("#select_user_add").val();

    $.ajax({
    async: false,  // For async, so it finishes running
    url: "get_ug.php",
    data: {
    id: txt
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function() {
        appendD = appendD + '<option id="usg' + this.id + '" value="' + this.id + '">' + this.label + '</option>';   
        $('#lgroup_' + this.id).css('background-color', '#CCFFCC');
        });

    }

});
$('#select_sub_group').append(appendD);
$("#loader").hide("fast");

    });
</script>
```

Racking my brain on this one .. It's either REALLY simple, or REALLY hard .. lol

Comment: I would remove `async: false` and put `$('#loader').hide("fast");` inside your `success` function.

Comment: @lbstr  --  Please submit an answer really quick ..  I'd like to give you the "green check mark". Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I've added an answer. Nothing more than a copy/paste of my comment, but it sounds like you get the idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove `async: false` and put `$('#loader').hide("fast");` inside your success function.

Answer (score 0):

Put this `$("#loader").hide("fast");` inside the `success:` function.

```
success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function() {
    appendD = appendD + '<option id="usg' + this.id + '" value="' + this.id + '">' + this.label + '</option>';   
    $('#lgroup_' + this.id).css('background-color', '#CCFFCC');
    });
    $("#loader").hide("fast");
}
```

Comment: I moved it inside, no effect.

Comment: Where is the `onclick` function, inside that, give the `$("#loader:hidden").show("fast");`!

Comment: If you look at the top of the code its called directly after $("#select_user_add").change  --   Same as a .click, but it's a <SELECT> menu, so there is no .click.

Comment: you had it almost right ..  I guess I had to take the async: false out whilst moving the hide into the success function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `beforeSend` callback to start your loader, then the `complete` callback to stop the loader.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I tried that to no avail, it still "blinks" the loader.    .....   beforeSend: function(){  $("#loader:hidden").show("fast");  },

Answer (score 0):

The container for your spinner should look like this in your HTML:

```
<div id="loader" style="display:none"></div>
```

To show the loader:

```
$("#loader").show("fast");
```

To hide the loader:

```
$("#loader").hide("fast");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ..  but I can get the thing to show, just not in the right order.